# script to redirect the output to a file not working with cron

Tags: bash, cron

I am trying to run the following script using cron for every hour

```
temp=`date`
date=${temp// /_}
exec 1>  /home/ec2-user/benchmarks/results/cpu/$date
sysbench --test=cpu --cpu-max-prime=100 run
```

The problem is output is not getting redirected to the file although the file is getting created.

Could anyone tell what might be the problem??????

Comment: Most of the time, when something works on the command line but not in cron, the problem is that cron does not run in *your* environment. cron's PATH is something like "/bin:/usr/bin". Where does "sysbench" live?

Comment: I am not sure about that. Could you please help on how to find that ?

Comment: Use `which sysbench` to find the path of that command and put the full path in your script. Also, avoid using `date` as a variable name (and a command).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is most probably that `sysbench` is not on the `PATH` used by cron jobs.

Instead of:

```
sysbench --test=cpu --cpu-max-prime=100 run
```

Use the absolute path of `sysbench`, for example:

```
/usr/local/bin/sysbench --test=cpu --cpu-max-prime=100 run
```

You can find the correct absolute path using `which sysbench`.